# What flutter widget should I use ? (a page slide to left)

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-web

I'm a highschool teacher in Japan. I would like to make a simple web exam app using flutter.

This is what I want to do.

1. A student choose an answer.
2. push an answer button.
3. page slides left to the next question.

[image]

I searched the Internet to find what widget should I use.

1. I use this one for radio button. https://gallery.flutter.dev/#/demo/selection-controls
2. I use this one for answer button. https://gallery.flutter.dev/#/demo/button
3. I couldn't find what to use. Should I use this one? https://gallery.flutter.dev/#/demo/motion

So, could you tell me what widget should I use to realize "push a button and the page slide to left" ?

Comment: You can use PageView for sliding screens

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use PageView and this page_view_indicator for page sliding. https://pub.dev/packages/page_view_indicators

And for push button you can see the material buttons. https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/widgets/material#Buttons